# string_split, reading in files and storing them into different lists

Tags: r

I have a character string of file names I want to read in.

They look something like:

Called: `files_to_read`

```
c:/file1/risk/2001
c:/file1/risk/2002
c:/file1/risk/2003
c:/file1/risk/2004

c:/file1/mgnt/2001
c:/file1/mgnt/2002
c:/file1/mgnt/2003
c:/file1/mgnt/2004
```

I am trying to create a function to read in the data and store them as a list: The following reads in all of the files in the character string and stores them in a single list:

```
readdata <- function(fn){

    dt_temp <- fread(fn, sep = ",")
    return(dt_temp)
  }

mylist <- lapply(file_to_read, readdata)
```

However I would like to store the results in 2 separate lists, one for `risk` and another for `mgnt`. I have the following which is not working:

```
readdata <- function(fn){
  function(split){
    risk <- str_subset(cosine_results, pattern = "risk")
    mgnt <- str_subset(cosine_results, pattern = "mgnt")
    dt_temp <- fread(risk, sep = ",")
    return(dt_temp)
  }
}

mylist <- lapply(files_to_read, readdata)
```

I thought about subsetting based on the `risk` and `mgnt` values and reading them in separately might create a list of lists but it breaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way of moving things around

```
readdata <- function(fn){      
  fread(fn, sep = ",")
}

lapply(c("risk", "mgnt"), function(x) {
  lapply(str_subset(files_to_read, pattern = x), readdata)
})
```

We just `lapply` over the different patterns you want to match and filter the list of files you are sending to read.data.

Comment: Thanks! This didn't exactly work on my actual data but I slightly modified the second part to the following based on your code: `mylist <- lapply(c("risk", "mgnt"), function(x) { lapply(str_subset(files_to_read, pattern = x), readdata)
})` which now creates a list of 2.

Comment: You can use `Map` rather than `lapply` to keep the names on the list.